# Pandas - function to conditionally update certain columns on the next row

Tags: python, pandas

I've ha csv file with a large number results from different soccer matches. 
The data looks something like the example below. 
The `result` column can contain 3 possible values:

- `H` -> Home team won   (home will get + 3 points)
- `A` -> Away team won   (away will get + 3 points)
- `D` -> Draw            ( both teams get +1 point)

```
   HomeTeam    AwayTeam Result
0   FC_Fake  ABC_United      H
1  Team_123   FC_Berlin      A
2   FC_FAKE    TEAM_123      D
```

I want to update the file so each row contains the total amount of points of each team `as they are at the start of the match` (So not yet updated for the results of the match played on the row itself)

I've used the following code to update the dataframe so it contains a `points_[TEAM_NAME]` dummy column for each team.

```
# Teams is a python list I extracted earlier
for team in teams:
    df['points_' + team] = 0
```

The goal is to transform the dataframe so that the example above turns into the example below.

(Again, the points should represent the situation at the start of the match. So even though `FC_FAKE` wins the match on the first row, the `Points_FC_FAKE` column is 0 )

```
HomeTeam | AwayTeam | Result  Points_FC_FAKE | Points_TEAM_123 | Points_FC_Berlin |  etc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 FC_Fake  ABC_United    H         0                  0             0
 Team_123 FC_Berlin     A         3                  0             0
 FC_FAKE  Team_123      D         3                  0             3
```

I've created the following python function that, if it iterates over all of the rows in the dataframe, should parse the result and award the correct amount of points to the right teams.

```
def point_updater(x):
    if x['Result'] == 'H':        
        home = x['HomeTeam']
        x.shift(-1)['points_' + home] += 3
        return x

    elif x['Result'] == 'A':        
        away = x['AwayTeam']
        x.shift(-1)['points_' + away] += 3
        return x

    elif x['Result'] == 'D':        
        home = x['AwayTeam']
        away = x['AwayTeam']
        x.shift(-1)['points_' + home] += 1
        x.shift(-1)['points_' + away] += 1
        return x
```

The problem is that I when I apply this function to the dataframe the points to not change (all remain 0)

```
df = df.apply(point_counter, axis=1)
df['points_FC_Fake'].value_counts()
----
0    2691
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So each teams gets a new column? For example `FC_Berlin` and `ABC_United` would also get a points column?

Comment: Correct! (I probably should have made that more clear, I'll update the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some exceptions we can use `iterrows` for this. Plus I made your code more fault proof and generic by doing some cleaning before starting the calculations:

```
# Convert to uppercase letters 
df['HomeTeam'] = df['HomeTeam'].str.upper()
df['AwayTeam'] = df['AwayTeam'].str.upper()

# get a list off all the teams in competition
lst_teams = list(set(list(df.HomeTeam.unique()) + list(df.AwayTeam.unique())))

# Create columns for each team
for team in lst_teams:
    df[team] = 0

# Iterate over each row and assign correct points
for idx, r in df.iterrows():
    if r['Result'] == 'H':
        df.loc[[idx], [r['HomeTeam']]] = 3
    if r['Result'] == 'A':
        df.loc[[idx], [r['AwayTeam']]] = 3
    if r['Result'] == 'D':
        df.loc[[idx], [r['AwayTeam']]] = 1
        df.loc[[idx], [r['HomeTeam']]] = 1

# Shift the rows one down, since points are only available at start of match
df.iloc[:, 3:] = df.iloc[:, 3:].cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
   HomeTeam    AwayTeam Result  ABC_UNITED  TEAM_123  FC_FAKE  FC_BERLIN
0   FC_FAKE  ABC_UNITED      H           0         0        0          0
1  TEAM_123   FC_BERLIN      A           0         0        3          0
2   FC_FAKE    TEAM_123      D           0         0        3          3
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a likely a more succinct way of performing these operations, but this should suffice for now. You can use `df.replace()` to map `Result` keys to their associated values and then use `pd.concat()` and `pd.DataFrame.pivot()` to achieve your desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam': ['FC_Fake','Team_123','FC_Fake'], 'AwayTeam': ['ABC_United','FC_Berlin','Team_123'], 'Result': ['H','A','D']})

remap = df.replace({'H': 3, 'A': 3, 'D': 1})

new = pd.concat([remap.pivot(columns='HomeTeam', values='Result'), remap.pivot(columns='AwayTeam', values='Result')], axis=1).shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int).cumsum()

final = pd.concat([df, new], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
   HomeTeam    AwayTeam Result  FC_Fake  Team_123  ABC_United  FC_Berlin  \
0   FC_Fake  ABC_United      H        0         0           0          0   
1  Team_123   FC_Berlin      A        3         0           3          0   
2   FC_Fake    Team_123      D        3         3           3          3   

   Team_123  
0         0  
1         0  
2         0
```

Answer (score 0):

change you function to this:

```
def point_updater(x):
    if x['Result'] == 'H':    
        home = x['HomeTeam']
        x['points_' + home] += 3
        return x

    elif x['Result'] == 'A':        
        away = x['AwayTeam']
        x['points_' + away] += 3
        return x

    elif x['Result'] == 'D':        
        home = x['HomeTeam']
        away = x['AwayTeam']
        x['points_' + home] += 1
        x['points_' + away] += 1
        return x
```

then add this in the end of your code:

```
df = df.apply(point_updater,axis=1)
for team in teams:
    df["points_" + team]= df["points_" + team].cumsum()
```